# create box plot of subcolumns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, boxplot

I have following pandas dataframe. I would like to create box (sub)plots of all the 5 columns (in one plot). How can I achieve this.

I am using following python statement but I am not getting the output.

df.boxplot(column=['synonym']['score'])

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of boxplot via `plotly.express`:

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x1=[1,2,3], x2=[4,8,12],x3=[1,5,10]))
df = df.melt(value_vars=['x1','x2','x3'])
fig = px.box(df, x='variable', y='value', color='variable')
fig.show()
```